# Inline ckeditor and keypress event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline

I use inline `Ckeditor` to edit content. I want to bind a `keypress` event to the div i edit. I mean, i need an event that will fire when i change the content of div.
Here is an example of how i do that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ckediv" contenteditable="true">Editing with CKEDITOR</div>
<br>  
 <script type='text/javascript'>
$( "#ckediv" ).keypress(function() {
     alert('cke key pressed');
     });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `keypress` is not fired in `ie` and `chrome` when i press `enter` or`delete` keys. If i make a div with contenteditable="true" but without Ckeditor then the event works well.
Here is a jsfiddle with code that shows how it works now http://jsfiddle.net/uAc7c/4/ .I don't know why, but for some reason this jsfiddle(keypress event) doesn't work in ie. When i tested locally with above source, it worked.
And here is a jsfiddle without Ckeditor that shows how it should work  http://jsfiddle.net/mPM4J/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Documentation says:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

So i guess IE and Chrome are two of the unsupported browsers.

Therefore try using the keyup event instead like this:

```
$( "#ckediv" ).keyup(function() {
     alert('cke key pressed');
     });
```

For more info, see here:
[KeyUp Documentation in the JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)